# Minipage too wide

Tags: graphics, margins, minipage

For the header of a document I'm using `minipage` to create two equally wide containers and then place an image (logo) in each of them.
Unfortunately the minipages are too wide although I set them to `.5\linewidth`.

Check out the MWE that generates the output of the image below. The two images should be flush with the frame of the page and not be indented on the left and overlapping on the right.

Thanks for any help.

---

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    verbose,%
    a4paper,%
    tmargin=3cm,%
    bmargin=3.5cm,%
    lmargin=2.5cm,%
    rmargin=2.5cm,%
    nomarginpar,%
    showframe=true%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm, left]{fig1}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm, right]{fig1}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: MWE Output]

Comment: You're missing `\noindent` before the first minipage